# How to get .NET ZipArchive to correctly store DateTimeOffset

Tags: .net, zip, php-ziparchive, datetimeoffset

The .NET `ZipArchive` class doesn't seem to correctly store the entry's `LastWriteTime` value.  I get that the file format only allows for a two second resolution.  But more than that, it seems to drop the offset as well.  For example:

```
       var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        using(var zipCreateArchive = new ZipArchive(stream, 
                                            ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
            var entry = zipCreateArchive.CreateEntry("Test");
            entry.LastWriteTime = now;
            using(var writer = new StreamWriter(entry.Open()))
                writer.WriteLine("This is a test");
        }

        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        using(var zipReadArchive = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
        {
            foreach(var entry in zipReadArchive.Entries)
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(entry.LastWriteTime);
        }
```

Upon creation, the `LastWriteTime` will have an offset of zero.  But when you read the value, it now has a non-zero offset because (apparently) it assumes the local time zone.  I can't seem to find the ZipArchive source anywhere, so I can't prove that's what's going on.  Any ideas as to how to correctly store the `LastWriteTime`?